# ComboBox with Filter

Tags: jquery, combobox, filter

Im trying to do a combo box with a filter inside the option

```
<head>
<link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="select2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { $("#e1").select2(); });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="e1">
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
...
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
</body>
```

im referred to using this link as a guide (http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) but it seems the first guide only has the drop downs with label and the search filter doesn't show up. Im quite confused on using this because its my first time to github.

Comment: I'm trying to insert a search filter for options on the option tab. but it only outputs the options.

Answer (score 0):

select2.js isn't a library but a plugin and for the plugins of jQuery to make work you need to include jQuery library

```
<head>
<link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--here you need to put the library, for eg: I'm including cdn version of jQuery 1.10.2-->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="select2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { $("#e1").select2(); });
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete example here,

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qecpx)

```
<head>
    <link href="http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-3.4.8/select2.css?ts=2014-05-01T06%3A52%3A24-07%3A00" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/select2-3.4.8/select2.js?ts=2014-05-01T06%3A52%3A24-07%3A00"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { $("#e1").select2(); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="e1">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        ...
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
</body>
```